# Backward function in PyTorch

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, gradient-descent, autograd

I have some question about pytorch's backward function I don't think I'm getting the right output :

```
import numpy as np
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
a = Variable(torch.FloatTensor([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]), requires_grad=True) 
out = a * a
out.backward(a)
print(a.grad)
```

the output is

```
tensor([[ 2.,  8., 18.],
        [32., 50., 72.]])
```

maybe it's `2*a*a`

but i think the output suppose to be

```
tensor([[ 2.,  4., 6.],
        [8., 10., 12.]])
```

`2*a.` cause `d(x^2)/dx=2x`

Comment: In short, `out.backward(a)` means tensor `out` takes `a` as incoming gradients from top neural layers, which are then multiplied element-wise with $\frac {\partial {out_i}}{\partial a_j}$

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Please read carefully the documentation on [`backward()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.backward) to better understand it.

By default, pytorch expects `backward()` to be called for the *last* output of the network - the loss function. The loss function always outputs a scalar and therefore, the gradients of the *scalar* loss w.r.t all other variables/parameters is well defined (using the chain rule).

Thus, by default, `backward()` is called on a scalar tensor and expects no arguments.

For example:

```py
a = torch.tensor([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], dtype=torch.float, requires_grad=True)
for i in range(2):
  for j in range(3):
    out = a[i,j] * a[i,j]
    out.backward()
print(a.grad)
```

yields

> ```
> tensor([[ 2.,  4.,  6.],
>         [ 8., 10., 12.]])
> ```

As expected: `d(a^2)/da = 2a`.

However, when you call `backward` on the 2-by-3 `out` tensor (no longer a scalar function) - what do you expects `a.grad` to be? You'll actually need a 2-by-3-by-2-by-3 output: `d out[i,j] / d a[k,l]`(!)

Pytorch does not support this non-scalar function derivatives.  Instead, pytorch assumes `out` is only an intermediate tensor and somewhere "upstream" there is a scalar loss function, that through chain rule provides `d loss/ d out[i,j]`. This "upstream" gradient is of size 2-by-3 and this is actually the argument you provide `backward` in this case: `out.backward(g)` where `g_ij = d loss/ d out_ij`.

The gradients are then calculated by chain rule `d loss / d a[i,j] = (d loss/d out[i,j]) * (d out[i,j] / d a[i,j])`

Since you provided `a` as the "upstream" gradients you got

```
a.grad[i,j] = 2 * a[i,j] * a[i,j]
```

If you were to provide the "upstream" gradients to be all ones

```py
out.backward(torch.ones(2,3))
print(a.grad)
```

yields

> ```
> tensor([[ 2.,  4.,  6.],
>         [ 8., 10., 12.]])
> ```

As expected.

It's all in the chain rule.

Comment: I realize this is a relative old post but in other words, it's calculating the vector-jacobian product a * (2 * a) right?

Comment: When you say that gradients are calculated by chain rule, you forgot about matrix multiplication. So it's not just (d loss/d out[i,j]) * (d out[i,j] / d a[i,j]), but in fact sum_{k,l} (d loss/d out[k,l]) * (d out[k,l] / d a[i,j]).

Comment: `*` is not matrix multiplication, just element-wis dot product.