# Why torch.sum() before doing .backward()?

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, pytorch, gradient-descent

I can see what this code below from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=330&v=_YMNYdvCUbw) is trying to do. But the `sum` from `y=torch.sum(x**2)` confuses me. With `sum` operation, `y` becomes a tensor with one single value. As I understand `.backward()` as calculating derivatives, why would we want to use `sum` and reduce `y` to one value?

```
import pytorch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
x = torch.linspace(-10.0,10.0,10, requires_grad=True)
Y = x**2
y = torch.sum(x**2)     
y.backward()

plt.plot(x.detach().numpy(), Y.detach().numpy(), label="Y")
plt.plot(x.detach().numpy(), x.grad.detach().numpy(), label="derivatives")
plt.legend()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can only compute partial derivatives for a *scalar* function. What `backwards()` gives you is `d loss/d parameter` and you expect a *single* gradient value per parameter/variable.
Had your loss function been a *vector* function, i.e., mapping from multiple inputs to *multiple* outputs, you would have ended up with multiple gradients per parameter/variable.

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57249287/1714410) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

You have a tensor `Y`, which has been computed directly or indirectly from tensor `X`.

`Y.backward()` would calculate the derivative of each element of Y w.r.t. each element of X. This gives us N_out (the number of elements in Y) masks with shape `X.shape`.

However, `torch.backward()` enforces by default that the gradient that will be stored in `X.grad` shall be of the same shape as `X`. If N_out=1, there is no problem as we have only one mask. That is why you want to reduce Y to a single value.

If N_out>1, **Pytorch wants to take a weighted sum over the N_out gradient masks**. But you need to supply the weights for this weighted sum! You can do this with the gradient argument:
`Y.backward(gradient=weights_shaped_like_Y)`

If you give every element of Y weight 1, you will get the same behaviour as using `torch.sum(Y).backward()`. 
Hence, the following two programs are equivalent:

```py
x = torch.linspace(-10.0,10.0,10, requires_grad=True)
Y = x**2
y = torch.sum(x**2)     
y.backward()
```

and

```py
x = torch.linspace(-10.0,10.0,10, requires_grad=True)
Y = x**2   
y.backward(gradient=torch.ones_like(Y))
```